# Are there more dialogues between God and man like in bhagvad geeta between Krishna and Arjuna?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, yama

I have heard of another dialogue between God Yama and Nachiketa. Are there few similar dialogues between God and man/woman? How could we approach god for such debates like Nachiketa or Arjuna or someone else?